# python having a hard time at my letter guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a guessing game in python but I cant figure some stuff out. I have to enter a word and it will print a lot of spaces and the person is suppose to guess the word. It has to look like this after the word it's been typed. The user will enter a letter and is suppose to look like this (word is dog):

> > Enter a letter:  a
> >
> > So far you have:
> >
> > ```
> >  ***
> > ```

if they guess the "o" for example, it will replace the * with an 'o' and so on until you get all the words right. And that's what I can't figure out, can somebody please help me? here is my program for far:

```
def main():
    letters_guessed = set()

    # Read word 
    word = input("\n Please Enter a word: ")
    # print 100 spaces
    print("\n" * 100)
    # Storing the length of the word
    word_length = len(word)
    guess = '*' * word_length


    while True:
        print ("So far you have: ", 

        guess_letter = input ("Please guess a letter: ")
        if len(guess_letter) != 1:
            print ("Please guess one letter at a time")
        if guess_letter in letters_guessed:
            print ("\n You already guessed that letter, please try again")
        letters_guessed.add(guess_letter)

        if set(word) == set(letters_guessed):
            break

    print("You won, the word is " % word)
```

Somebody tried to help me but I just didn't understand how this works because I am new to the program, I want to be able to understand it also. Thank you. Here it was his output, just part of it.

```
while True:
    print ("So far you have: ", "".join([c if c in letters_guessed else "*" 
for c in word]))
    guess_letter = input ("Please guess a letter: ")
```

Comment: your code doesnt run properly, `print ("So far you have: ",` this line isn't complete it seems and your 'you won' message is printed inside the while loop,

Answer (score 1):

I'll first explain the solution code you received. The following code:

```
[c if c in letters_guessed else "*" for c in word]
```

generates a list. If you see square brackets [  and ] , then we're list likely creating a list.

now what your friend is using is a generator. It's a short way of creating a for loop. In other words, this would do the same thing.

```
word = "dog"
letter_guessed = "go"
ourList = list() #new list
for letter in word: #we check every letter in the word
    if letter in letter_guessed: #if our letter has been guessed
        ourList.append(letter) # we can show that letter in our word
    else:
        ourList.append("*") # if the letter has not been guessed, we should 
        # not show that letter in our word, and thus we change it to a *
print(ourList)
```

This gives us the following list: ["*", "o", "g"]

What your friend then does, is take that list, and use join:

```
"".join[ourList]
```

This is a good way of turning a list of letters back into a string.

See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

---

Your own code has a few problems. Is it possible you didn't copy everything?

In python, using tabs effects the way your program runs. Because you put a tab before

```
print("You won, the word is " % word)
```

you'll run this line every single time, rather than only when the break statement is activated!

You have a similar problem with .add! Try to see if you can't spot it yourself.

I also recommend writing

```
print("You won, the word is " + word)
```

because this is much easier to use. (for more advanced formatting, look up .format() see https://pyformat.info/